# Selenium on Python with Geckdriver crashes when not in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I'm trying to use Selenium on a jupyter notebook with geckodriver.

Although on headless mode it seems to work fine, I need to see the browser window since I'm learning...

I've checked that both browser and driver are compatibles, driver it's added on the PATH variable and a few more tips I've seen around...

This works fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("http://google.com/")
print ("Headless Firefox Initialized")
driver.quit()
```

But when removing the headless option, it crashes:

> WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process

The only clue I can find its in the **geckodriver.log** where I can read:

> 1596560987355  mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilejjh45q"
> Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified

I've checked that that variable exists and it's like **DISPLAY:0**. I've also tried to change the value, to set it to my ip and port....

This is driving me a bit mad so if anyone can give my hand it would be awesome!!
Thanks in advance!!

--> Update: as @Wunderbread suggested, SeleniumBase works without problem.

--> Update: I was working Selenium on Jupiter Hub. Neither works on jupyter tree or PyCharm or VSC, but..... works perfect from a script on the terminal... life has mysteries.... xDD

Comment: If I'm not mistaken head/less is dependent on the type of geckodriver you have installed – you *may* need to have a non-headless driver installed, or at the least point to one.

Comment: Hi!! I haven't see anything about two different drivers, but I'll have a look!! Thx for your time!!

Comment: there's one geckodriver here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases but if you want to save time, use an existing test suite. 

I would suggest using SeleniumBase which does a lot of the tedious work for you. Check that out here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase

Comment: @Wunderbread be blessed!! I've been two days fighting against this issue but your advice about SeleniumBase just worked on the first try!! Thank you so much!!
I still would like to know what was my mistake but this it's perfect for me!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're deleting the `options.headless = True` and the driver is looking for that option. Set the headless option to `options.headless = False`

Or write something where headless becomes an optional argument like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium import webdriver

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

UPDATE: I suggested using SeleniumBase as it provides the groundwork for you regarding test suite setup.

However, it's worth noting that using the following code I was able to toggle between headless and using the browser for tests. I used homebrew for my local geckodriver requirements on Mac OS 10.15.6 and Python 3.8

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hi!! thx, but if tried both and it remains the same... as defect, headless value it's set to False...

It's funny in someway because every issue with Selenium seems to be realted with not able to go headless... in my case it's just the opposite...

Comment: I would make sure that you're using the latest driver binary and if the issue persists create a github ticket https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/

Comment: @Pablo Selenium is all fun :)